# How Do I save a video file to a custom assets library?

Tags: objective-c, alassetslibrary

I have recorded a video with AVFoundation to a temp directory.  I want to instead save it to photos library.  I was able to create a custom library with `addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:albumName`.  I see that a new folder appears in the photos app.  However, I have no idea how to save my newly created .mov files that I have created in my temp dir.  All of the methods in ALAssetLibrary seem to write to the "saved photos" album.  How do I save to my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to first save it, then move it.

```
[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqual:<YOUR ALBUM NAME>]) {
            *stop = YES;
            [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                [group addAsset:asset];
            } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }];
        }
     }];
}];
```